# How to initialize an array with values to later be realloced in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I've got about 12000 pre known values that I need to place in an array early in the program. Given certain circumstances, I will later need to resize this array with realloc. Is there any way to initialize an array with malloc/calloc with values, or fill an array with several other values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot initialize a `malloc`ed array this way, your best chance is to have it statically in your program, and copy it to a `malloc`ed array at the beginning of the run, e.g.:

```
static int arr[] = {1,2,3,4};
static int * malloced_arr;

// in the init function
malloced_arr = malloc(sizeof(arr));
if (malloced_arr)
{
    memcpy(malloced_arr, arr, sizeof(arr));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of thing that zero length arrays are useful for.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct values {
    int x[4];
    int y[0];
} V = { {1, 2, 3} };

int
main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    int *t;
    int i;
    struct values *Y;

    (void) argc; (void) argv;
    /* Allocate space for 100 more items */
    Y = malloc( sizeof *Y + 100 * sizeof *Y->y );
    t = Y->x;
    memcpy( Y, &V, sizeof V );
    t[3] = 4;

    for( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        printf( "%d: %d\n", i, t[ i ]);

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, this is really just a parlor trick that gains you nothing over Binyamin's solution, and introduces a lot of totally unnecessary obfuscation.

Comment: It would be better if you could have shown in your code how he can access all the members of both the arrays(x & y) using the same index. Your last loop shows only accessing the values of x. But, I suppose of values of y also can be accessed using 't' contiguously. Am I right?

Comment: You write yourself that it gains nothing over Binyamin's solution. So what's the point?

Comment: @jay yes, t[4] through t[103] can be accessed.

Comment: @ugoren  The point is that, although not exactly appropriate in this scenario, zero length arrays do server a useful purpose and the OP's situation might change slightly (or a reader of the question may have a slightly different problem) and the technique might be useful to someone who is unfamiliar with it.